# Textarea that takes all remaining space after header

Tags: html, css, height, textarea

I am trying to make a `textarea` that takes all remaining space after header `div`.

Requirements:

- Header is of variable height depending on content.
- Textarea must take all remaining height after header.
- If there is too much content in textarea, scroll bar appears.

Basically, I am trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/hLd7jc9x/, but without height in % (because height of header must be variable depending on content and not a fixed %). For the same reason, textarea also can't be positioned with `fixed` or `absolute`. I know this is simple to achieve with `div` but somehow I can't figure out how to do it with `textarea`.

This is my current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/t5862grv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've revised your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5862grv/3).

The main solution is using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). To account for no flexbox support, we use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs) for detection, and add a little custom jquery-based height-updating logic (with support for window resizes). To account for js being turned off (rarer these days), we go back to your old fiddle's percent-based height styling.

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#a { background: #F00; }
#b { background: #0F0; resize: none; }

/* Don't forget to use Autoprefixer or similar, so you cover all the necessary vendor prefixes based on your browser requirements. */
.flexbox body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.flexbox #a { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.flexbox #b { flex: 0 1 100%; }

/* When browser doesn't support flex, i.e. IE9, use the old, less flexible styling. This can also be replaced with a JS script to manually resize the textarea height. In fact, the custom height setting is set to only be a backup if js isn't allowed. */
.no-flexbox #b { width: 100%; }
.no-js.no-flexbox #a { height: 10%; }
.no-js.no-flexbox #b { height: 90%; }
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    // Guard.
    if (!Modernizr.flexbox) {
        return;
    }

    // Define.
    var $container = $('body');
    var $header = $('#a');
    var $textarea = $('#b');
    function updateTextArea() {
        var height = $container.innerHeight() - $header.outerHeight();
        $textarea.height(height);
    }
    var requestAnimationFrame = (
        window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame
    );

    // Run.
    updateTextArea();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(updateTextArea);
    });

})
```

Comment: Thank you and upvoted! I was hoping for a CSS solution but if there is no such solution I will accept your JS solution. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: So the flexbox solution is purely css. It's only for IE9 and below that you'd need to switch to js. If you don't need IE9 support you can safely not include the js and any of the non-flexbox css.

Comment: Sorry! Herp derp on my part :)